# How to replay history using rebase instead of merge in order to clean up pull request?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

A colleague is new to git. He's been working on some feature branch for quite some time and created a PR now (Azure DevOps if that matters).

Unfortunately, he was not aware of `git rebase` and so he used `git pull origin master` all the time to synchronize which resulted in quite some merge commits. (there are 20 "real" commits and 9 merge commits on his feature branch)

Now, this would be fine, but the result is that the diff views of the PR not only show his changes, but also all the other changes that were applied on master in the mean time. It's basically impossible to do a proper code review now because his changes are indistinguishable from all the other changes.

Now, my plan is to somehow replay all of his changes, but whenever he did a merge I will do a rebase instead. Whenever there is a conflict during rebase, mixing in the changes of the corresponding merge commit should perfectly resolve that (in theory). Most of the merges are quite difficult, so it's not an option to redo them manually, as this work has been done already.

What's the best way to achieve that?

1. I tried `git rebase master`, but this doesn't include the merge commits, so they would have to be done manually.
2. I also tried `git rebase --preserve-merges master`, but for some reason this will only do the rebase up until the latest merge commit (see below).

If there is no better option, I will have to do 20+9 cherry-picks...

---

Talking in pictures, the situation is this:

```
A---B---C- ... --D---E---F         master
 \   \      ...   \         
  G---m---H- ... --m---I---J       feature
```

And I want this:

```
A---B---C- ... --D---E---F                                   master
                          \                          
                           G'--m'--H' ... --m'--I'--J'       feature
```

Option 1. will only give me this, but I want to obtain the `m`s (not necessarily as commits, but I want those resolved conflicts, somehow):

```
A---B---C- ... --D---E---F                                   master
                          \                          
                           G'------H' ... ------I'--J'       feature
```

Option 2. will only give me this, not helping much:

```
A---B---C- ... --D---E---F                 master
 \   \      ...   \       \         
  G---m---H- ... --m-------m'--I'--J'      feature
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that worked quite smoothly:

1. Get yourself in exactly the state he was in when starting the work on feature

   ```
   git checkout -b replay_feature <hash-of-A>
   ```
2. Redo exactly what he did until he did a merge:

   ```
   git cherry-pick <hash-of-G>       # redo his non-merge commit(s)
   ```
3. Now, he did `git merge master`, so I do `git rebase master` instead:

   ```
   git rebase <hash-of-B>            # back then, B was HEAD of master
   ```
4. Now I'm in the rebase progress, facing exactly the same conflicts he faced and which he resolved with `m`. So, in order to resolve it exactly the same way he did, I'm just checking out all conflicting files from his merge commit.

   ```
   git checkout <hash-of-merge> -- file-in-conflict.cpp    # do this for all conflicts 
   # make sure everything compiles
   git add .
   git rebase --continue
   ```
5. repeat step 4. until the rebase is done

Repeat steps 2. to 5. until his entire work is replayed, replacing all merges with rebases and applying his conflict resolutions. In the end, compare the branches `replay_feature` and `feature`. If everything went fine, all files should be identical.

```
git diff replay_feature feature    # should not show anything
```

Comment: This should work fine. You can even use `git checkout <hash-of-merge> -- .` if there are conflicts upon rebasing on each master-side parent of each merge commit. The merge commit's snapshot should be the desired final tree. (This means that instead of literal cherry-picks, you could also just build a new sequence of commits using `git commit-tree` plumbing commands.) The tricky part here is that if you make a mistake, it's really easy to build a bogus sequence of commits as there's less checking going on.

Answer (score 2):

Rebase can't do that.  It either drops merges entirely, or *re-performs* merges.  If it re-performs merges, the merge commits you get are actual merge commits.  In your case you want the equivalent of cherry-picking with `-m`.  (I think you want `-m 1`, but make sure, especially before using the below.)

> If there is no better option, I will have to do 20+9 cherry-picks...

That's the way to go.  Use `git rev-list` or similar to list out all the commits to be copied.  Mark down which of them are merges.  Then write a little script-let:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-G>
git cherry-pick -m 1 <hash-of-merge#1>    # or maybe -m 2?
git cherry-pick <hash-of-H>
```

and so on.  Run each command one at a time so that you know where you are if and when one fails, or if you're sure enough about handling errors, run it as a script with `-e` set so that a cherry-pick failure stops the rest of the picking.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me some good inspiration. In the end, I found an even nicer way how to leverage the existing conflict resolutions. Have a look at my answer.